# UK dependant Visa Supporting Documents

Tags: united-kingdom, family

I am applying for UK dependant visa under Tier 2 Dependant. Regarding the supporting documents,  is marriage certificate endorsement by Ministry of External Affairs required? I am applying from India. Kindly answer

Comment: The UK publishes very detailed guidance about the documents you should submit.  Did you read it? What did it say? What part of it did you have trouble understanding?

Comment: There was no details of the above said attestation in any website. But it was mentioned by vfs agency when I called

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UK Visitor Visa Supporting Documents](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8152/uk-visitor-visa-supporting-documents)

Comment: @oskarpearson the question you marked as a duplicate was closed as off topic because it concerned a visitor visa.  This question is about a Tier 2 visa, which is on topic for this site.

Comment: @phoog they were asked by the same person on the same day. The other question didn't include the type of visa, and this seems to be the clarification. One of them should probably go as a duplicate. Thanks!

Comment: @oskarpeterson the visitor visa *is* a type of visa. It would be more accurate to characterize this as a correction of the other question than as a clarification. Still, the other one was closed, so it makes no sense to close this one.

Answer (score 1):

The [guidance notes for applicants and dependents requires evidence](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/562983/VAF2_Form_Guidance_October_2016.pdf) of a marriage that is legally recognised and documented and continue to be currently married. For the document to be accepted in a country other than that in which it was issued, it generally requires an apostille or attestation. In India,

> [The Ministry of External Affairs](http://mea.gov.in/apostille.htm) attests original documents//true copies of documents for use abroad. Attestation done by the Ministry of External Affairs is of two types:
>
> **1. Apostille:** 
>   India, since 2005, is a member of the Hague Convention of October 5, 1961 that abolished the requirement of legalization of foreign public documents. Apostille is acceptable in 105 member-countries of the Convention (For more info please visit the website: www.hcch.net). Apostille is done for personal documents like birth/death/marriage certificates, Affidavits, Power of Attorney, etc. and educational documents like degree, diploma, matriculation and secondary level certificates etc. Any document Apostilled in one member country is acceptable in all the other 104 member-countries, signatory to the referred convention of 1961 thus greatly simplifying the process of attestation by making it needless to get the documents attested in each or for each of the countries separately.
>
> **2. Normal Attestation:** 
>   This is done for all the countries which are not a member of Hague Convention and where Apostille is not accepted.